# How to execute shell commands from Python bypassing Admin rights?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I want to stop and or start a service when I run my Python code. But, unless I run cmd as admin I can't do so. How would I go about fixing this?

```
p1 = subprocess.run(['sc', 'start', 'AdobeARMservice'], shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
print(p1.stdout)
```

`Output:  [SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 5: Access is denied.`

Comment: The same way you would do it from the shell: use `sudo`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah ok, so forgot to mention Im in windows but I assume its the runas?

Comment: maybe, I don't know windows

Comment: If they made it easy to bypass admin rights, every virus ever invented would do so.

Comment: So yea it seems `runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd` did the trick. Its like sudo for windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run python script with `sudo` or give that user permission to run start that service.